# ¿Cómo podría traducir "Naive Bayes Classifier"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas

¿Cómo traducirían `Naive Bayes Classifier` al español?

Por ahora tengo la traducción como *Clasificador Bayesiano ingenuo*, pero no me siento seguro respecto a la traducción. De hecho, ¿consideran que podría dejar la expresión como un anglicismo?

Comment: No me suena mal dejarlo en inglés (sobre todo porque es un neologismo muy específico y de un área que se ha desarrollado especialmente en inglés), pero depende de tu público: en España, por ejemplo, puede ser más relevante buscar una traducción que en otros países. Ojo: naïve es una palabra francesa que también se usa como extranjerismo en castellano.

Comment: @Rafael cierto, pero la RAE lo ha adaptado como *[naíf](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QDMAhNK)*. Su cuarta acepción es precisamente "ingenuo, inocente".

Comment: Llama la atención que en Wikipedia en inglés equipara la palabra "naive" con la palabra "strong" cuando dice "
"with strong (naive) independence".
Sería interesante saber porqué el (o los) primer autor que estudió o describió "Naive Bayes Classifier" usó la palabra "naive".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efectivamente se usa la traducción literal "[clasificador bayesiano ingenuo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clasificador_bayesiano_ingenuo)". De todas formas es razonable esperar que tu audiencia comprendiera el anglicismo. Por ejemplo, en [este artículo de IBM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SS3RA7_17.1.0/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita/clementine/dbmining_ibm_naivebayes.html) sobre *minería de datos* se refieren a él tanto como "Bayesiano ingenuo" como "naïve"

> **Bayesiano ingenuo** es un algoritmo muy utilizado para resolver problemas de clasificación. El modelo se denomina **naïve** porque trata todas las variables de predicción propuestas como independientes unas de otras

Y lo mismo para [este otro artículo](https://silvercorp.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/clasificador-naive-bayes/)

> El clasificador probabilístico Naive Bayes o Bayesiano ingenuo en español, tiene sus fundamentos en el Teorema de Bayes [...]

Comment: Es interesante que en estos artículos escriban _Bayesiano_, con mayúscula. Supongo que es por imitación del inglés, pues deberían llevar minúscula.

Comment: Tal vez por el apellido de Thomas Bayes? Por ser nombre propio?

Comment: @carpinchosaurio será, pero cuando actúa como adjetivo no se pone mayúscula. Decimos _España_ pero _español_, por ejemplo. Véase el artículo sobre las [mayúsculas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp) en el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas.

Comment: muy interesante @fedorqui, comprendido

Answer (score 7):

"Clasificador bayesiano naíf" podría ser otra alternativa. "Naíf" es correcto en castellano con el significado de "ingenuo", y también se admite sin tilde (naif).

En francés ingenuo se dice "naïf" (se pronuncia más o menos como "naíf", con acento en la i), y su femenino es "naïve" (que se pronuncia "naív", casi igual).

Parece más adecuado para un "clasificador" (masc) tomar el español "naíf", también masculino, que dejar el inglés naive, originalmente femenino, y que no es español propiamente.

Comment: Muy de acuerdo. No hay necesidad de importar un término inglés que viene del francés si ya lo habíamos importamos directamente :)